# Cannot get value from config in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to change the timezone in lumen, but I cannot get the value from config, it always give the default value `UTC`.

I've tried everything I know, to the point changing the default value to what I wanted. But still the timezone wont change

AppServiceProvider

```
public function register()
    {
        //set local timezone
        date_default_timezone_set(config('app.timezone'));
        //set local date name
        setLocale(LC_TIME, $this->app->getLocale());
        
        URL::forceRootUrl(Config::get('app.url'));
    }
```

Bootstrap.app

```
(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__)
))->bootstrap();

date_default_timezone_set(env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'Asia/Jakarta'));

$app->configure('app');
```

Config.app

```
'timezone' => env("APP_TIMEZONE", "Asia/Jakarta"),
```

.env

```
APP_TIMEZONE="Asia/Jakarta"
APP_LOCALE="id"
```

Also if I make a variable inside config.app such as:

```
'tes_var' => 'Test'
```

And using it like this:

```
\Log::info(config('app.tes_var'));
```

The result in Log is null, I can't get the value from `tes_var`.

I don't have any idea what's wrong here, if it's in Laravel maybe this is happened because cached config, but there's no cached config in Lumen. Maybe I miss some configuration here?

Thanks

Comment: What file is `Config.app` ? is it a typo for `config/app.php` ?

Comment: app file inside Config folder, default laravel folder structure

Comment: Also, if starting a new project in 2022, it's more preferred to use laravel instead of lumen. If you're optimizing for performance/concurrency, then laravel octane yields better result than lumen

Comment: Btw my server doesn't support php 8, so I choose Lumen because it is more faster for php 7. I can't use anything like octane, and I can't update the php version on my server

Comment: Can you ensure that you load the config in your bootstrap.
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: @AaronT yeah `$app->configure('app');` I've included it in my question

Comment: oh sure, a shared hosting I guess

Comment: I don't know if there is a typo on your question but `tes_var` != `test_var` perhaps that's why you get nothing

Comment: @Kristian I'm just a junior programmer, I don't have any privilege to make any change to the server. This is the first time I encountered this problem, on my other project everything working perfectly

Comment: @Lk77 sorry, that's a typo in the question

Answer (score 1):

First, you should create the `config/` directory in your project root folder.
Then create a new file app.php under the config directory i.e. config/app.php

Now add whatever config values you want to access later in your application in the config/app.php file.

So, instead of creating a config.php file you should make a `config` directory and can create multiple config files under the config directory.

So final code will be like this:

config/app.php will have:

```
<?PHP
return [
   'test_var' => 'Test'
];
```

Can access it anywhere like this:

```
config('app.tes_var');
```

Although Lumen bootstrap/app.php has already loaded the app.php config file (can check here: https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/9.x/bootstrap/app.php)
If not loaded in your case, you can add the below line in bootstrap/app.php file:

```
$app->configure('app');
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the env file while caching the configs, you need to create a env.php inside the config folder. Then, load all env variables and read as "env.VARIABLE_FROM_ENV". Example env.php:

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

$envVariables = [];

$loaded = Dotenv::createArrayBacked(base_path())->load();

foreach ($loaded as $key => $value) {
    $envVariables[$key] = $value;
}

return $envVariables;
```

then read in your code:

```
$value = config('env.VARIABLE_FROM_ENV', 'DEFAULT_VALUE_IF_YOU_WANT');
```